# Python VS2017 intellisense not working for files in subfolders

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

So, if I move a python file to a subfolder and use it, e.g. `from SubModule.MyMod import *`, the application runs perfectly, but I'm missing the great Intellisense provided by Visual Studio.

On the other hand, the module can be apparently imported ignoring the subfolder, `from MyMod import *`, although the file is indeed in the subfolder. Then intellisense works, but the application won't run since it won't find the module in runtime.

I would appreciate if anyone can provide any idea to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have__init__.py in your subfolder?

Comment: @LouisNg I should have said I'm a newbie... Searched for the purpose of this file. now I know... it works. Do you want to add it as a response so I can close the question? Thanks!

Comment: @LouisNg, could you please add a answer with your comment when you have free time, it seems solved Haplo's issue and then Haplo can mark it to close, thanks.